# Prolog reversing a list - fast method

Tags: list, prolog

I'm trying to write a code in order to reverse a list in Prolog.

The result of my work is :

```
reverse(X,X).
reverse([X|Y],[H|X]):-
    reverse(Y,H).
```

I ran this code on prolog but it doesn't work.
The fact that is seems correct to me and i cant find the errors.
Can you help me ?

Comment: you need an auxiliary predicate : **reverse(X,Y) :- reverse_h(X, [], Y).**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach uses an empty accumulator list (as mentioned by joel76 in the comments) which gets filled with the elements of a list in reverse order one after another.

```
%  reverse/2
%  reverse(List,Result)
%  
%  Result will be the reversed list that gets returned
reverse(List,Result) :-
    % call the accumulator method with the list and an empty placeholder list
    reverse(List,[],Result).

%  reverse/3
%  reverse(List,Accumulator,ReverseList)
%  
%  >> stop rule for recursion
%  -- checks whether initial List is empty (aka the reversing process is done)
%  -- returns the ReversedList if completed, otherwise carry ReverseList over throughout the next iteration
reverse([],ReversedList,ReversedList).

% actual reversing method
reverse([Head|Tail],RestTail,ReverseList) :-
     reverse(Tail,[Head|RestTail],ReverseList).
```

When executing these statements in SWI with e.g. `reverse([a,b,c,d],X).`, the idea behind it gets clearer:

```
 ?- reverse([a,b,c,d],X).
     Call: (7)  reverse([a,b,c,d],          _G2273) ?
     Call: (8)  reverse([a,b,c,d],[],       _G2273) ?
     Call: (9)  reverse(  [b,c,d],[a],      _G2273) ?
     Call: (10) reverse(    [c,d],[b,a],    _G2273) ?
     Call: (11) reverse(      [d],[c,b,a],  _G2273) ?
     Call: (12) reverse(       [],[d,c,b,a],_G2273) ?
     Exit: (12) reverse(       [],[d,c,b,a],[d,c,b,a]) ?
     Exit: (11) reverse(      [d],[c,b,a],  [d,c,b,a]) ?
     Exit: (10) reverse(    [c,d],[b,a],    [d,c,b,a]) ?
     Exit: (9)  reverse(  [b,c,d],[a],      [d,c,b,a]) ?
     Exit: (8)  reverse([a,b,c,d],[],       [d,c,b,a]) ?
     Exit: (7)  reverse([a,b,c,d],          [d,c,b,a]) ?
 X = [d,c,b,a].
```

**Explanation:** Imagine the initial list being a stack of elements. Each of the initial list's elements get cut from itself by doing list-splitting like `[Head|Tail]`. `Head` will be added to the accumulator list by making a new list `[Head|ReverseTail]`. `RevserseTail` is simply the current content of the accumulator list, so the currently reversed list gets the initial list's `Head` added at first position, while the tail follows after. The following step will be to call reverse/3 recursively with the `Tail` part as the remainders of the initial list, `[Head|ReverseTail]` as the current reverse list, and `ReverseList` which has no other purpose other than serving as the value to be returned when the process is finished.

This will be repeated until all elements of the initial list were added to the accumulator one by one and the initial list is empty, which is when the recursion stops and the reversed list is returned.